# Make 'n' always search forwards, regardless of whether / or ? was used for searching

Tags: vim, editor, shortcut

I almost always search in Vim with `/`, and then continue searching forwards with `n` and backwards with `N`. Sometimes, however, I use `?` to jump to an item just a few lines above the line I'm currently at, and in that case, if I want to search the same item forwards, I have to use `N` instead of `n`, an annoying mental speed bump.

So my question is: is it possible to make `n` always go forwards, and `N` backwards?

P.S. Documentation seems to hint that it's not possible, since `n` simply "Repeats the latest "/" or "?" [count] times", but who knows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was taken from [ZyX's post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/8jSoA931P2Y/Nk1_Bj6kGDwJ) on the vim mailing list.

```
noremap <expr> n 'Nn'[v:searchforward]
noremap <expr> N 'nN'[v:searchforward]
```

It maps `n` to the original N or n based off of the variable `v:searchforward` by indexing `'Nn'` as a list of two elements. This only works because the mapping is non-recursive. If it was recursive this would call it self and you would be in an infinite loop.

When `v:searchforward == 1` (search forward) the mappings are equivalent to

```
noremap <expr> n n
noremap <expr> N N
```

and when `v:searchfoward == 0` (search backwards) the mappings are equivalent to

```
noremap <expr> n N
noremap <expr> N n
```

This mapping works in Normal, Visual, and Operator pending modes.

---

I probably would have written it like this. (Although I'm not sure this is any clearer)

```
noremap <expr> n (v:searchforward ? 'n' : 'N')
noremap <expr> N (v:searchforward ? 'N' : 'n')
```

Comment: Whoa, that's one ingenious mapping.

Comment: By the way, as this thread was popped out I have a new solution for “You're right, but in the first place I wanted 
     /pattern 
     d//e(hit Enter as-needed) to be repeatable with 
     n.n.n.n.” complaint.

Answer (score 6):

That is just the way it is, notwithstanding some debate on the developers' mailing list ...

Here's what you can do about it:

```
:noremap n /<CR>
:noremap N ?<CR>
```

Relevant mailing list thread with a lot more interesting info: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/8jSoA931P2Y/JklYtxFOiAYJ

Comment: I don't seem to lose the `/e` flag.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I confused it with `:s` and didn't test enough. I wonder if there's another problem, the solution seems almost too simple ...

Comment: I like Zyx's answer at the bottom of the thread. (And where I was going if I could find that variable if you hadn't posted first) `noremap <expr> n 'Nn'[v:searchforward]` and 
    `noremap <expr> N 'nN'[v:searchforward]`

Comment: Too bad, Bram won't include my patch. This is one of my biggest annoyances with vim.