# Is it possible to make ; and , after f t F T always move forward and backward (respectively) in Vim?

Tags: vim

I've used this answer for / and ? [Make 'n' always search forwards, regardless of whether / or ? was used for searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523150/make-n-always-search-forwards-regardless-of-whether-or-was-used-for-searc) but can't seem to find anything for ; and ,

I don't like having to think about what direction I'm going. Any ideas?

Comment: You might consider using/modifying http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3877. I don't think there is a variable predefined that will allow you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Besides other features, This [plugin](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim) provides setting for that.

```
let g:incsearch#consistent_n_direction = 1
```